# Harmonic function takes both positive and negative values

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions, maximum-principle

I am a little confused on the following question:

Suppose that $u$ is harmonic nonconstant on a $D(z_0,R)$ and $u(z_0)=0$. Is it true that on each circle $C(z_0,r)$, with $0<r<R$, the function $u$ will take both positive and negative values?

I think the following should be a counterexample, but I am not so sure:

$f(z)=0$ if $|z|\le 1$, $f(z)=\ln|z|$  for $|z|>1$, $R=2$.

Comment: Recall that harmonic functions always 0 laplacian--that is the second derivatives in the x and y direction sum to 0. This counterexample you've provide though is not differentiable on the unit circle!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a function is harmonic then it satisfies the mean value property on any circle inside the region in which it is harmonic:

$$u(z_0) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}u(z_0+re^{i\theta})d\theta$$

If $u(z_0)=0$, then if the function takes any positive values (strictly greater than 0) on the circle $|z-z_0|=r$, then it must clearly also take negative values in order for the mean to equal zero.

It is easy to see that your example $f(z)$ cannot be harmonic, since if we take a small circle centered at $z=1$, then $f$ takes values equal to zero on the part of the circle inside the unit disk and strictly positive values on the part of the circle outside the unit disc, which would make it impossible for the mean to be zero.

Comment: Ok, everything is clear indeed, but then if we try to prove the statement is true, what guarantees us that for any r, there will exist a value where u(z) on C(z0,r) will be non-zero?

Comment: @guest From the Poisson integral formula, if $u$ were to be zero on the circle $|z-z_0|=r$, then it would be zero at all points inside the circle, and then by the identity theorem, it would be zero everywhere (at least everywhere inside a connected domain). You could also prove this using the maximum-principle on the disc $|z-z_0|\leq r$.

Comment: So, esentially the question is to prove that if we start with an analytic function on a connected domain D, and if it is constant in an open subset of D, it is constant everywhere in D. Is there an elementary proof of this, without using the identity theorem?

Comment: If you know the result that the zeros of an analytic function on a connected open set are discrete, then that would do it, and I think this should be a fairly easy deduction from the power series representation of an analytic function.